# Near-neighbor Point Cloud Downsampling/Decimation

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, downsampling, pyvista, decimation

I'm looking for a way to downsample a point cloud based on the proximity of points to their neighbors (from what I can tell, this is synonymous with "decimation"). While I am currently using PyVista as my main library, I'm not seeing any class/methods that seem to achieve what I am looking for since the `decimate` method that does belong to the [PolyDataFilter](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyDataFilters.decimate.html#pyvista.PolyDataFilters.decimate) class is only for points that have been meshed (and I want to decimate my point cloud before meshing).

Without developing my own method from scratch, how can I achieve this decimation?

Answer (score 3):

PyVista developer here ;)

I think you may want to try the `clean()` filter in PyVista (sort of only available for `PolyData` types -- which your point cloud would be). We actually have a [snippet of code](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/blob/93a7b58fddcf0498084d1292e031927e56b5de33/pyvista/core/filters/data_set.py#L2342-L2354) internal to the `glyph()` filter that demonstrates this when needing to downslample points in this fashion for glyphing many geometries as a representative sample of large vector field. [The example in our docs](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.DataSetFilters.glyph.html#pyvista-datasetfilters-glyph) demonstrates this with a toy data set. But you aren't glyphing! So below is a snippet that hopefully works for your use case. The key here is going to be the `merge_tol` argument for determining proximity. Please refer to our active documentation for using this.

```py
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np

source_points = np.random.rand(10_000, 3)
dense = pv.PolyData(source_points)

# Recomend reading PyVista's docs on how to use this parameter
# the gist: tolerance is in terms of fraction of bounding box diagonal length (0-1)
tolerance = 0.05

# This can take some time for large point clouds
small = dense.clean(
    point_merging=True,
    merge_tol=tolerance,
    lines_to_points=False,
    polys_to_lines=False,
    strips_to_polys=False,
    inplace=False,
    absolute=False,
    progress_bar=True,  # eh, not sure why its non-interactive
)
```

Then plot it of course, cuz this is PyVista!

```py
pl = pv.Plotter(shape=(1, 2))
pl.add_mesh(dense, render_points_as_spheres=True)
pl.subplot(0, 1)
pl.add_mesh(small, render_points_as_spheres=True)
pl.link_views()
pl.view_isometric()
pl.show()
```

[image: comparison of dense and downsampled point clouds]

> from what I can tell, this is synonymous with "decimation"

Hm, the terminology here is definitely confusing. In PyVista, decimation is currently reserved for reducing the number of ***triangles*** in a mesh. I think "downsampling" is the best term for this and agree that it is not obvious the "clean" filter would be what you need (PRs for improving our documentation are always welcome)

Comment: How does/would this compare to `open3d`'s `farthest_point_down_sample` method?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `open3d` to speculate on that. I can point you to what we are leveraging from VTK in PyVista though for you to research: we leverage `vtkCleanPolyData` which itself uses `vtkMergePoints` for this reduction